# How to verify email id authenticated by Google or not when we signup using the Firebase for android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When users signup using the Firebase Email/Password `SIGN-IN METHOD` in android, how can we verify their Emails ?

Comment: Refer the link: [Custom email handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)

Comment: i need to verify email without using the Auth..so for this reason i post this question and want to find the other way to verify email.

Comment: there is a feature in firebase from which you can verify email address by sending a confirmation link to their email address. and then it can be verified and the above link is for that purpose only. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For Android Email verification, first you can view the documentation by firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users).

> Send a user a verification email

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.sendEmailVerification()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Email Sent.");
            }
        }
    });
```

**In my App** whenever a user registers, `sendEmailVerification();` is triggered

```
 private void sendEmailVerification() {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    user.sendEmailVerification()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                      Log.d(TAG, "Email verification sent.");                  
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Using the previous method, your users will now be provided with a verification Email. And it will look something a lot like this

[image]

Did they verify their email ?

```
 private void IsEmailVerified() {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user.isEmailVerified()) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Email is verified.");
    } else {
          Log.d(TAG, "Email is not verified !.");
    }

}
```

Sadly, you may not customize the content/body of your verification Email ( I have been heavily corresponding with Firebase to provide alternative less hideous looking templates ). You may change the title or the message sender ID, but that's all there is to it.

Not unless you relink your application with your own supported Web. [Here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714).